# How do I vertically align text in table row after form

Tags: html

How do I vertically align text in table row after form, in his code the Serial No field is significantly lower than everything else.

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <b>SongKong discount)</b>
    </td>
    <td  valign="top">
        £40 ($50 USD)
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <form name="paypalpro" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="5UC5KAYZ6JZR8">
            <input alt="PayPal" type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" border="0" name="submit">
            <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
            Serial No: <input type="textfield" name="serialno"/>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the vertical alignment of the input to top:

```
form[name=paypalpro] input{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/edn6dfnq/1)**

The default vertical alignment of inline elements is `baseline`, which is what you were seeing.

Comment: thanks but can i add this css to my html just for this, i dont want to mess with my global css stylesheet because of possible sideeffects

Comment: Sure, you can change the selector to `form[name=paypalpro] input{`

Comment: could you add to the answer please I tried and it didnt work but Ithink I have the formatting wrong

Comment: @j0891 sorry for being dense but where does it go, is it going within the <form> element ?

Comment: Oh, writing CSS inline isn't recommended. I was giving you the CSS to put in a stylesheet or `<style>...</style>` block. Otherwise if you have to use inline CSS you'd just apply the `vertical-align:top` to your inputs.

Comment: ah thats okay i just didnt realize it was gpoing inside <style> tag ion the page, sort of forgot yo could do that to be hones, okay its now working